# set an iPhone microphone arrray

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, core-audio, microphone

I was reading that iphone has 3 microphones. But when I check the available inputs I only get the "built in microphone". I want to get access to the microphones to implement a noise reduction algorithm so the microphones has to record at the same time. So I have two questions:

How can I get the iphone microphones as a microphone array?

Is it possible to record from all microphones at the same time?  How should I set them? (I think that I should use an AVAudioSessionCategoryMultiRoute)

I'm getting the available inputs with this function:

```
NSArray* inputs = [[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] availableInputs];
```

Comment: What device are you using?

Comment: possible duplicate of [The iPhone 5 has 3 mics. Can I change from which one I'm recording?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20600839/the-iphone-5-has-3-mics-can-i-change-from-which-one-im-recording)

Comment: I try with an iPhone 5 and iPhone 6 .

Comment: Thanks JAL. I didn't see that question I'm going to check it.

Comment: I check "The iPhone 5 has 3 mics. Can I change from which one I'm recording?"  and is not a duplicate because I want to create an microphone array so the three microphones has to be recording at the same time. I edited my question.